# Split string with ignore special RegEx substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I need split the string, split character is "," but must skip content in "("...")".

```
const paramString = "gyro (param1, param2), proximity, Ultra Wideband (UWB) support, compass";

const paramArr = paramString.match(/[^(\)\,]+(\(.+?\))?/g).map( item => item.trim() );
```

In my result is paramArr[2] bad.

```
[ "gyro (param1, param2)", "proximity", "Ultra Wideband (UWB)", "support", "compass" ]
```

I need result:

```
[ "gyro (param1, param2)", "proximity", "Ultra Wideband (UWB) support", "compass" ]
```

Please advise how update my RegEx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use negative lookahead. You are basically selecting all commas (with spaces after them to trim them) that are not followed by a `)` if there is no `(` before it:

```js
const paramString = "gyro (param1, param2), proximity, Ultra Wideband (UWB) support, compass";
const paramArr = paramString.split(/,\s*(?![^(]*\))/);

console.log(paramArr);
```

NOTE: it won't work for nested parentheses. It will fail in the following scenario:

```
const paramString = "gyro (param1, (param2)), proximity, Ultra Wideband (UWB) support, compass";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below mentioned regx , this will break your string in expected tokens only.

```
/[\w\ ]+(\([^)]*\))?(\ \w+)?/gi
```

The regx breaks your string in following tokens .

```
gyro (param1, param2)
 proximity
 Ultra Wideband (UWB) support
 compass
```

Please follow the link for live demo of the regx :

https://regex101.com/r/yCYHgw/1

https://regex101.com/r/yCYHgw/2

---

(updated, regx to work only with non nested )

Comment: I think your solution is not perfect for nested ones. It can take care continuous `)` but cannot not continuous `)` like `gyro (param1, (param2, param3), param4)`. I think perfect solution for nested one is not possible with regex. In addition, you need no escape for space. So `space` is enough instead of `\space`.

Comment: yes, that's right  it not perfect for nested all possible nested one, I think requester can check if solution for nested ones is needed or not .  if it more of nested than I think there is need to have custom logic implemented to handle this.